# Problem with macro behaviour in lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

If in the REPL I do this:

```
(dolist (x (1 2 3))
  (print x))
```

then I get an error since in (1 2 3) the digit 1 is not a symbol or a lambda expr. 
If I do:

```
(dolist (x (list 1 2 3))
      (print x))
```

then it works ok.

My question is why the following works:

```
REPL> (defmacro test (lst)
           (dolist (x lst)
             (print x)))
=> TEST
REPL> (test (1 2 3))
1
2
3
=>NIL
```

Why does dolist accept (1 2 3) when it is inside the macro definition but not when  directly in the repl?
The assumption:

"Since TEST is a macro ,it does not evaluate its arguments, so (1 2 3) is passed as is to the dolist macro. So dolist must complain like it does when it is passed (1 2 3) in the REPL"

is obviously wrong. But where?

UPDATE: Although the answers help clarify some misunderstandings with macros, my question still stands and i will try to explain why:

We have established that dolist evaluates its list argument(code blocks 1, 2). Well, it doesnt seem to be the case when it is called inside a macro definition and the list argument that is passed to it is one of the defined macro arguments(code block 3). More details:
A macro, when called, does not evaluate its arguments. So my test macro, when it is called, will preserve the list argument and will pass it as it is to the dolist at expansion time. Then at expansion time the dolist will be executed (no backquotes in my test macro def). And it will be executed with (1 2 3) as argument since this is what the test macro call passed to it. So why doesnt it throw an error since dolist tries to evaluate its list argument, and in this case its list argument (1 2 3) is not evaluatable. I hope this clears my confusion a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros get their arguments passed unevaluated. They may choose to evaluate them. `dolist` does that for its list argument. It works with an unquoted list passed in for `lst` in your macro `test`:

```
(defmacro test (lst)
  (dolist (x lst)
    (print x)))
```

That's because at macro-expansion time the `dolist` sees `lst` as its argument. So when it evaluates it, it gets the list `(1 2 3)`.

Answer (score 5):

This form:

```
(defmacro test (lst)
  (dolist (x lst)
    (print x)))
```

defines a *macro*, which is a "code transformation function" which
gets applied to a form using this macro at macro expansion time.  So,
after you have defined this macro, when you evaluate this expression:

```
(test (1 2 3))
```

it first gets read to this list:

```
(test (1 2 3))
```

Then, since Lisp reads `test` at the operator position, it gets
macro-expanded by passing the argument, which is the literal list `(1
2 3)`, to the macro expansion function defined above.  This means that
the following gets evaluated at macro-expansion time:

```
(dolist (x '(1 2 3))
  (print x))
```

So, at macro-expansion time, the three values get printed.  Finally,
the return value of that form is returned as the code to be compiled
and executed.  `Dolist` returns `nil` here, so this is the code returned:

```
nil
```

`Nil` evaluates to `nil`, which is returned.

Generally, such a macro is not very useful.  See "Practical Common
Lisp" by Peter Seibel or "On Lisp" by Paul Graham for an introduction
to useful macros.

---

*Update:* Perhaps it is useful to recapitulate the order of
reading, expanding, and evaluating Lisp code.

First, the REPL takes in a stream of characters: `(` `t` `e` `s` `t` 
 `(` `1`  `2`  `3` `)` `)`, which it assembles into
tokens: `(` `test` `(` `1` `2` `3` `)` `)`.

Then, this is translated into a tree of symbols: (`test` (`1` `2`
`3`)).  There may be so-called *reader macros* involved in this step.
For example, `'x` is translated to (`quote` `x`).

Then, from the outside in, each symbol in operator position (i.e., the
first position in a form) is examined.  If it names a macro, then the
corresponding macro function is invoked with the *code* (i.e., the
subtrees of symbols) that is the rest of the form as arguments.  The
macro function is supposed to return a new form, i.e. *code*, which
replaces the macro form.  In your case, the macro `test` gets the code
(`1` `2` `3`) as argument, prints each of the symbols contained within
(note that this is even before compile time), and returns `nil`,
throwing its arguments away (the compiler never even sees your little
list).  The returned code is then examined again for possible
macroexpansions.

Finally, the expanded code that does not contain any macro invocations
anymore is *evaluated*, i.e. compiled and executed.  `Nil` happens to
be a self-evaluating symbol; it evaluates to `nil`.

This is just a rough sketch, but I hope that it clears some things up.

Comment: what i dont understand is why the form (1 2 3) that i pass to the macro call becomes '(1 2 3) at macro expansion time instead of staying (1 2 3)

Comment: @Paralife:  It is still `(1 2 3)`, it just does not get evaluated.  I simulated the actual evaluation by inserting `quote`, which produces a literal.

Comment: @Svante: Then why the direct dolist in the REPL tries to evaluate (1 2 3) when I do (dolist (x (1 2 3)) (print x)) in the repl? dolist is a macro isnt it? ...I think the workings of quote is the source of all confusion...

Comment: @Paralife: because the code that the DOLIST macro expands to just happens to place the object `(1 2 3)` in a position where it will be evaluated.  You can see it with the form `(macroexpand-1 '(dolist (x (1 2 3)) (print x)))`.

Comment: As a side note, DOLIST does that evaluation of its argument list because it's very useful. If it didn't, you could pass nothing but literal lists to it, but no variables or function results.

Comment: @Rord, @Cirno: That exactly is what confuses me: Since dolist evaluates, (test (1 2 3)) should throw an error since this call executes dolist (at expansion time) with (1 2 3) as list argument. And (1 2 3) is not evaluatable! See my update

Comment: @Paralife: No, DOLIST's list argument at macro expansion time is not (1 2 3), but lst. And it evaluates lst to get (1 2 3).

Comment: @Rord Thanks. That clarified everything. It is too difficult to think at 2 levels at the same time. You should post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @Rord also this implies that in nested macro calls expansion begins from the inside macro first. Am i correct?

Comment: @Paralife:  As I have written above, expansion is from the outside in.  I do not see what would imply the inverse.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mistype.

Answer (score 4):

Your macro `test` does not return any code. And yes, macro arguments are not evaluated. If you want to see the same error, you have to define your macro as:

(defmacro test (lst)
     `(dolist (x ,lst)
         (print x)))

Answer (score 4):

Generally when you have questions about macro expansions, referring to `MACROEXPAND-1` is a great first step.

```
* (macroexpand-1 '(test (1 2 3)))

1 
2 
3 
NIL
T
```

IE, what is happening is that the *actual* expansion is that sequence of prints.

Nil is what is returned by `DOLIST`, and is the expanded code.

Comment: My problem has to do with what happens at expansion time but before the printing. Why doesnt the dolist throw an error since it is called with an argument that is not evaluatable? (note thatdolist evaluates its list argument). See my update

Answer (score 0):

lst is a variable, when expand macro test, it also mean eval dolist structure. the first step is to eval the form lst, will get the lisp object (1 2 3).

like follow example:

(defmacro test (a)
   (+ a 2))

(test 2) --> 4 ; mean invoke add function, and the first variable a binding a value 2.